# Code runs but Tkinter window stays blank

Tags: python, tkinter

The problem i'm having is that it even though it executes, the tkinter window remains blank. and as a side issue the window doesn't refresh to update the Actions checkbutton.

```
from tkinter import *
Pieces = {}
Actions =[]
class GameCreation(Frame):
    def __init(self,master):
        super(GameCreation,self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.CreatePiece()
   #Creating pieces function 
    def CreatePiece(self):
        Label(self,text ="What piece are we working with?").grid(row =0,
                                                             column = 0,
                                                             sticky = W)
        self.piece_entry = Entry(self)
        self.piece_entry.grid(row =0,
                          column = 1,
                          sticky = W)

        Label (self, text = "Tick all the actions which the piece has").grid (row =1,
                                                                          column = 0,
                                                                          sticky = W)
        self.Actions = BooleanVar()
        self.Actions.set(None)

    column = 0
    row = 4
        for action in Actions:
            Checkbutton(self,text = action, variable = self.checkButton, value = action).grid( row = row,
                                                                                           column = column,
                                                                                           sticky = W)
            if column == 5:
                row +=1
                column = 0
            else:
                column +=1
        Button(self,text = "Add action", command = self.AddAction).grid(row = 1,
                                                                    column = 0,
                                                                    sticky = W)
        self.action_entry = Entry(self)
        self.action_entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)


        Button (self, text = "Create piece and it's actions", command = Add_to_dict).grid(row =2,
                                                                                      column = 0,
                                                                                      sticky = W)
        self.Add_dict = Text(self, width =10, height = 2, wrap = WORD)
        self.Add_dict.grid( row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 4)
```

This function should add to the Actions list

```
    def addAction(self):
        action = self.action_entry.get()
        Actions.append(action)
```

This function should just print the name of the piece and the actions chosen for it

```
    def Add_to_dict(self):
        actions = Actions.get()
        piece = piece_entry.get()
        rules = piece, ":", actions
        self.Add_dict.delete(0.0,END)
        self.Add_dict.insert(0.0,rules)
```

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: Are you creating an instance of `GameCreation`?

Comment: Python in its standard form isn't compiled, so it being run has no meaning but only the 'main' code is valid. You can have gibberish as classes and you'll still be fine if you never call them in 'main'.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `__init__`, not `__init`

Also, if you're using `BooleanVar`, you must set it to `True` or `False`, not `None`:

```
self.Actions.set(False)
```

Also, you have a method named `addAction` but you are calling it like `self.AddAction`, and you have a method named `Add_to_dict` that you are calling like `Add_to_dict` rather than `self.Add_to_dict`.

And finally, you don't appear to be creating an instance of GameCreation anywhere.